# Can Boost Spirit be used to parse byte stream data?

Tags: c++, parsing, stream, boost-spirit

Can Spirit (part of Boost C++ library) be used to parse out binary data coming from a stream?  For example, can it be used to parse data coming from a socket into structures, bytes, and individual bit flags?  Thanks!

Comment: can you give more details on the format of the data.  Is it some complex format?

Comment: I don't recall what I had in mind when I asked this originally, but it probably had to do with recognizing SSL/TLS headers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Boost Spirit allows for a parser to be defined using [Extended Backus–Naur Form (EBNF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) syntax with [template meta-programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming). It is very flexible and uses abstract classes in all phases of the parsing process that can be customized. In order to process a binary data stream, you would need to implement custom scanner classes since the default types are tailored for text input. You can read further in [The Scanner and Parsing](http://spirit.sourceforge.net/distrib/spirit_1_8_5/libs/spirit/doc/scanner.html) section of the [Spirit User's Guide](http://spirit.sourceforge.net/distrib/spirit_1_8_5/libs/spirit/index.html).

In my humble opinion, binary data streams are best handled with hand rolled serialization code. Spirit is geared more towards well formed grammars like mark-up or scripting languages. For example, [The Complete Syntax of Lua](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#8) is provided in EBNF. So, it might make sense to use Spirit to build a custom parser. On the other hand, a proprietary serial data link with synchronization bytes and CRC bracketing messages would require a lot more work just to define the EBNF if a [context-free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) even exists for it.

**Addendum**

[The latest version of Boost Spirit includes functionality for dealing with binary data.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/binary.html)

Answer (score 9):

Spirit2, just released, has facilities for parsing binary. [Check out this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/binary.html).